# Questions about Microsoft Identity Manager

Tags: active-directory, identity, credentials

I am not sure the forum to ask this question I figured right here would be good.  My company wants me to figure out how to get all of the credentials linked up between a new application and our active directory.  I think this would be a good job for MIM (FIM)...  The resources I found on Microsoft's website are very limited and try to push you to download the trial copy of the application.  I just want to know from anyone with some experience if using MIM would help to synch up our credentials between our apps and AD and if so are there any good sources of information or test cases out there that I can present my boss with?

Edit:  I don't want to annoy anyone so if this is posted in the wrong area please let me know and I will gladly move it.

Edit 2:  Let me rephrase... are there any suggestions for an app or a custom built piece of software that will manage identity and allow for inclusion/exclusion from windows access rights based on a profile.... EG the employee is Corporate... they get access to x folders.... The employee works for abc division therefor he has access to different set of folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MIM to sync data to/from various systems. AD can certainly be a source, HR is often a common source as well. Your destination application can either use one of the built-in connectors if possible (e.g. a database or web services connector), or there is an SDK to build your own connectors.

As far as passwords go, you can synchronize password resets/changes in AD to connected applications as they occur. You cannot, however, extract existing passwords from AD and pass those to other applications.

Comment: But existing objects in AD would be synchronized with the applications, correct?  Also can MIM synchronize group membership in AD as well as revoke and apply access rights to network resources?  Maybe it would be AD group based security.

Comment: Correct. MIM can synchronize group membership. Typically it doesn't apply direct access rights, but those rights are instead controlled via groups (which MIM would manage).